# Joomla 2.5 page load extremely slow

Tags: joomla, xampp

Hi everyone I have installed Joomla 2.5 with a quickstart template on localhost Xampp, it works all fine except the fact that is running very slow the site on each time i click an article to read or a menu.

My try!

I have already tried all possible plug ins for optimization which minify js and css  but none of them seems to work in my case.
I have also deleted some of the extensions that i dont use.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're using a fresh copy of Joomla, then it's not Joomla itself causing the problem, it could either be a slow computer, something wrong with your browser, or something wrong with Xampp. Try using [WAMP](http://wampserver.com/en) instead

Comment: Is any of the process mysqld or htppd taking too much memory or CPU during page load? Also what are you server configuration?

Comment: I am running it on my localhost using Xampp.. what do u mean exactly by configuration?

Answer (score 0):

When installing joomla, instead of using localhost as your host on the second page for the database, I used 127.0.0.1 and this speed up the website by a lot. I did that after changing the hosts file as it does not improve the situation alone. But I am not sure if this has any effect after I upload the files on a server.

If you have already installed it, then go to global configuration, under server and change mysql server from localhost to 127.0.0.1

I hope someone else find this useful because this alone got me stuck for 2 days!